# Broken bar/coumn chart in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way, in matplotlib, to plot a broken bar/column chart. The case I seek has one bar that is on a larger scale than the others. An example from Excel looks like this: [example](http://www.andypope.info/charts/brokencolumn.htm)

I have looked in the Matplotlib gallery and documentation and found broken bar methods, but they are not quite the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two methods for making a discontinuous axis for a line plot are laid out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656798/python-matplotlib-is-there-a-way-to-make-a-discontinuous-axis). It should be essentially the same process (in either case) for a bar graph.  Please leave a comment if either method does not work.

Comment: This is great! I wish I had searched "discontinuous" rather than "broken", but your answer helped tons! I had to upgrade to most recent MPL to find the subplots method of pylab. Great help though - thanks!

Comment: would you mind sharing your solution to a bar chart with a broken axis?