# How to exclude San and Sat from matplotlib graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I have pandas DataFrame like this:

```
2013-09-13 20:51:00
2013-09-13 20:52:00
2013-09-13 20:53:00
2013-09-13 20:54:00
2013-09-13 20:55:00
2013-09-13 20:56:00
2013-09-13 20:57:00
2013-09-13 20:58:00
2013-09-13 20:59:00
2013-09-16 00:00:00
2013-09-16 00:01:00
2013-09-16 00:02:00
2013-09-16 00:03:00
2013-09-16 00:04:00
2013-09-16 00:05:00
2013-09-16 00:06:00
2013-09-16 00:07:00
2013-09-16 00:08:00
```

there is no Sun and Sat date. Matplotlib pyplot draws so:

[image]

Is it possible to crop the image except emty date? Like this:
[image]

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656798/python-matplotlib-is-there-a-way-to-make-a-discontinuous-axis) is full or suggestions for a discontinuous axis.

Answer (score 0):

If you plot a series with null values (or a masked array) in matplotlib, the line will be broken at the location of the nulls.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.plot([1, 2, 3, np.nan, np.nan, 6, 7, 8, 9])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Therefore, what you want to do is add `NaN`'s for the weekend dates.  `pandas` offers a few different ways to do this.  There's [an overview here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html), but basically you want to look at the `asfreq` and `resample` methods.

As an example with your dates:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dates = """2013-09-13 20:51:00
2013-09-13 20:52:00
2013-09-13 20:53:00
2013-09-13 20:54:00
2013-09-13 20:55:00
2013-09-13 20:56:00
2013-09-13 20:57:00
2013-09-13 20:58:00
2013-09-13 20:59:00
2013-09-16 00:00:00
2013-09-16 00:01:00
2013-09-16 00:02:00
2013-09-16 00:03:00
2013-09-16 00:04:00
2013-09-16 00:05:00
2013-09-16 00:06:00
2013-09-16 00:07:00
2013-09-16 00:08:00"""
dates = pd.to_datetime(dates.split('\n'))

# Generate some random y-data...
y = (np.random.random(dates.size) - 0.5).cumsum()

# Resample to a regular 1-minute interval series
# By default, this will put NaNs in where there isn't any data...
data = pd.Series(y, index=dates).asfreq('1Min')

data.plot().set(title='Resampled data')
plt.show()
```