# plotting multiple time series simultaneously in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have data divided into different periods of time. The time-series is continuous for eg(one data set is for february then next on April and next in Jan 2016) But how can I reduce the gap of the year 2015 in between> It really just wastes the space and shrinks the graph

I can plot them together like the image below. Any way to remove the time-stamps in between?

[image]

Comment: Manually set the xticks and xtick labels?

Comment: Either you'll have to modify your x-values to remove the gaps, a adjust the x-ticks and labels, or you could create "gaps" in your x-axis as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32185411/break-in-x-axis-of-matplotlib

Comment: As an alternative, you could generate a row of three subplots, one per continuous subrange (see https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html for examples).

Comment: Is the date itself important? It's hard to tell from your question, but perhaps changing the x-axis to be "days from start of monitoring period" may be more appropriate. That would then allow all three of your series to be plotted along the same axis. Generally having a non-continuous date axis is very confusing to interpret and can be quite misleading.

Comment: @DavidG that was my next idea. But I wanted to see if it's possible without doing that

Comment: Yeah I can do that @Hans,Thanks just wanted to know if it could be done in one graph

Comment: @KenSyme date is important because it helps in visualizing the place where values become outliers

Comment: @DizietAsahi I will look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a pandas DataFrame then this should work and it is a little tidier than the above answer:

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, sharey=True)

for (col, data), ax, c in zip(df.iteritems(), axes):
    data.dropna().plot(ax=ax, rot=30, legend=True)
```

Comment: No, DateTime Index is important, I don't want to remove it. Having to keep date-time index is why the problem occurred in first place

Comment: Sorry, this wasn't clear. I your answer might be best but with some tidying. I will edit.

Comment: @Yash this should work and is a lot more readable and concise :)

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution, which isn't exactly what I was looking for but fulfills the purpose. I modified the solution posted of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982418/discontinuous-timeseries-plot-with-dates-on-x-axis) link:

```
fig=plt.figure()
fig,(ax,ax2,ax3) = plt.subplots(1,3,sharey=True)
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.05)
fig.set_size_inches(20, 3, forward=True)

ax.plot(healthyde['timestamp'],healthyde['value'],label='healthy',color='g')
ax2.plot(healthynde['timestamp'],healthynde['value'],label='detection',color='y')
ax3.plot(healthylde['timestamp'],healthylde['value'],label='fault',color='r')

ax.set_xlim(healthyde['timestamp'].iloc[0], healthyde['timestamp'].iloc[-1] )
ax2.set_xlim(healthynde['timestamp'].iloc[0], healthynde['timestamp'].iloc[-1] )
ax3.set_xlim(healthylde['timestamp'].iloc[0], healthylde['timestamp'].iloc[-1] )

labels = ax.get_xticklabels()
for label in labels:
    label.set_rotation(30)

labels = ax2.get_xticklabels()
for label in labels:
    label.set_rotation(30)

labels = ax3.get_xticklabels()
for label in labels:
    label.set_rotation(30)

ax.legend()
ax2.legend()
ax3.legend()

plt.show()
```

**Output:**
[image: plot]