# Use matplotlib to plot dataframe that has gaps in date

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe like below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
period0 = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=50, freq='D')
period1 = pd.date_range('18/5/2012', periods=50, freq='D')
period2 = pd.date_range('7/11/2014', periods=50, freq='D')
df = pd.concat((pd.DataFrame(period0), pd.DataFrame(period1), pd.DataFrame(period2)), axis=0)

df['y'] = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(150,1))
```

These dates and periods are arbitrarily chosen to create some gaps and dates.

When I try to plot the dataframe, matplotlib automatically draws a line in between the date gaps:

```
plt.plot(df[0], df['y'])
```

Result:
[image]

I also tried to `dotplot`. But it didn't prevent the plot from creating the line:

```
plt.plot(df[0], df['y'], ':')
```

Result:
[image]

And I also found a [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39231410/ignoring-time-gaps-larger-than-x-mins-matplotlib-in-python). Unfortunately, it didn't solve my problem.

So, what should I do?

Comment: Have you considered using a scatterplot instead of a line plot?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't modify your existing index, you could try :

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key=0, freq='1D'))['y'].last().plot()
```

Comment: Wow! It miraculously did what I wanted. Thanks for the answer man.

Answer (score 1):

You should define values you do not want to see as NaN:

https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/nan_test.html

For example:

```
df.index = df[0].astype('datetime64')
#defining df[0] as index

idx = pd.date_range(start = '1/1/2011', end = max(period2), freq='D')
#creating new index

df = df.reindex(idx)
#reindexing df - it preserves values from 'y'

plt.plot(df.index, df['y'])
#creating plot
```

Comment: Actually I'm not able to write a function for it. It's a bit hard for me, since I have multiple dataframes like this. Could you please add some pseudo code?

Comment: The code works. Thanks for this valuable code. I really appreciate it. But when I try to run the code multiple times, I get this error: `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest reindex(idx) adds new indexes and for rows with no data in df['y] procudes NaN

Comment: My previous comment was meant to help improving the answer.