# python module brokenaxes - how to handle error message: ylims is not defined

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to use brokenaxes to create a histogram with a broken y-axis in python. I found how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656798/python-matplotlib-is-there-a-way-to-make-a-discontinuous-axis/44541588?noredirect=1#comment76073755_44541588).

to get a break between 4 and 80 I did:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from brokenaxes import brokenaxes

bax=brokenaxes(ylims((0,4),(80,100)))
```

and got the error

> name 'ylims' is not defined

Actually, I had some problems installing the package because it seems to be broken (see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44543238/cant-find-brokenaxes-module)) therefore I downloaded the brokenaxes.py file from https://github.com/bendichter/brokenaxes. When I open this file in notepad it seemed to me a bit unstructured because line breaks are missing but I could fix that with the help of the github link above. still the error message is the same.

I must confess that I don't understand all scripts in brokenaxes.py but at least I can see that there is a definition of ylims...
Anyway I am not sure if I do it wrong or if the packages has a bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen from [the documentation](https://github.com/bendichter/brokenaxes) the syntax is

```
bax = brokenaxes(ylims=((0,4),(80,100)))
```

Comment: o god, i'm sorry. I had too look at your code 10 times until I saw the difference :-/