# Smoothing and breaking x-axis with datetime index in matplotlib python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, time-series

Using this code

```
pivoted = df.reset_index(level=0).pivot_table(index='date', 
columns='Speaker', values='raw_score')
resampled = pivoted.rolling(450, min_periods=1).mean()
resampled.plot()
```

I have produced this graph

[image]

However I would like to create a break in the x-axis which will remove some of the data in the middle that I am not interested in displaying. The broken x-axis, would span between 1992-2000 and 2006-2017 (leaving out 2000-2006). Any help would be useful, also if someone has suggestions for better smoothing that would be helpful too!

This question is different than the question that is linked below because my x-axis is a datetime object and is the index of my df 'resampled', which is a pivot table. Here is what my df 'resampled' looks like:

```
       Speaker    Allison   Cohn    Hoenig   Hubbard   etc...  
       date                                                                     
 1992-03-12       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  1.174405     
 1992-05-11       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.847486      
 1992-05-14       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.417312
```

[Python/Matplotlib - Is there a way to make a discontinuous axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656798/python-matplotlib-is-there-a-way-to-make-a-discontinuous-axis)

Comment: You could use try use interpolation to smooth the graph. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html

Comment: It's not very clear what do you mean by "truncate the x-axis". Do you want two chart with the two periods or do you want to create a break in the x-axis which will remove some of the data in the middle that you are not interested in displaying?

Comment: I want to `create a break in the x-axis which will remove some of the data in the middle that you are not interested in displaying`. Sorry for the confusion, I will edit the question now.