# Exclude range of dates in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

So I am plotting some 5k time date using matplotlib, using a modified tutorial. I want to remove the ranges between `year-01` and `year-07` for all years, to make the data more interesting.

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

def plotTimes(data):
    x = data["x"]
    y = data["y"]
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.grid()

    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.xlabel('Date')
    plt.ylabel('5k Time')
    plt.title(data['name'])
    plt.show()
```

- How can I exclude a range of dates from my plot?
- (side question) Is pyplot the best way to use matplotlib?
  [image: Exclude date range problem]

All code:
https://pastebin.com/raw/MQVa5QLZ

This is the data:

```
{'x': [datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 28, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 
9, 3, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 10, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 17, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 26, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 29, 0,
 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 3, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 16,
 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 22, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 10,
 23, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 27, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015,
 10, 30, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 4, 0, 0), 
datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 26, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 10, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 13, 0, 
0), datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 15, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 24, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 27, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 
14, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 20, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 
10, 21, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 25, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 29, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 2, 0,
 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 25, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 9, 
0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 12, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 
14, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 23, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017,
 9, 27, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 7, 0, 0), 
datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 28, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 1, 0, 
0)], 'y': [datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 20, 4, 100000), 
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 19, 59, 700000), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 18, 48, 100000), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 18, 26),
 datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 18, 49, 600000), datetime.datetime(1900,
 1, 1, 0, 17, 57), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 18, 28, 200000), 
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 17, 34, 800000), datetime.datetime(1900,
 1, 1, 0, 17, 46), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 17, 57, 700000), 
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 17, 43, 200000), datetime.datetime(1900,
 1, 1, 0, 17, 54, 700000), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 17, 40, 
700000), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 17, 55, 600000), 
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 18, 29, 200000), datetime.datetime(1900,
 1, 1, 0, 17, 43, 300000), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 17, 51), 
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 18, 12, 500000), datetime.datetime(1900,
 1, 1, 0, 17, 30, 100000), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 17, 9, 
800000), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 17, 58), datetime.datetime(1900,
 1, 1, 0, 17, 16, 800000), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 17, 43, 
600000), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 17, 12, 400000), 
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 17, 31, 600000), datetime.datetime(1900,
 1, 1, 0, 17, 36, 700000), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 17, 13, 
900000), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 17, 17,
700000), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 16, 42), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0,
     16, 56, 200000), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 17, 11, 700000),
 datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 16, 51, 900000),
 datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 17, 15, 200000), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 17, 9, 
700000),
 datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 16, 55, 600000), 
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 17, 2, 400000)], 'name': 'Jack Santinga'}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656798/python-matplotlib-is-there-a-way-to-make-a-discontinuous-axis or https://matplotlib.org/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/broken_axis.html?highlight=broken%20axis

Comment: What do you mean by `year-01` and `year-07`? Do you mean all the dates between January and July (both inclusive) should be excluded from the axis labels? In the data you wrote above, there is no date for January to July

Comment: yes. I want to remove those from the plot, so that long horizontal line isn't there.