# About plotting axis in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, axis

everyone! I am working with `matplotlib` and would like to manipulate the x-axis.
I wonder how I can hide part of the axis as in the following image.
[See the example image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqyjD.png)
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack overflow. I'll post an answer shortly but please bear in mind (for the future) that it's often preferred if you explain to the community what solutions you have tried already, and what the obstacle you have encountered is.

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking to do is to create two plots, and draw them onto the same figure.

Please refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5669301/4447297 which contains an example. :)

The example is below as well:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

# If you're not familiar with np.r_, don't worry too much about this. It's just 
# a series with points from 0 to 1 spaced at 0.1, and 9 to 10 with the same spacing.
x = np.r_[0:1:0.1, 9:10:0.1]
y = np.sin(x)

fig,(ax,ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True)

# plot the same data on both axes
ax.plot(x, y, 'bo')
ax2.plot(x, y, 'bo')

# zoom-in / limit the view to different portions of the data
ax.set_xlim(0,1) # most of the data
ax2.set_xlim(9,10) # outliers only

# hide the spines between ax and ax2
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.yaxis.tick_left()
ax.tick_params(labeltop='off') # don't put tick labels at the top
ax2.yaxis.tick_right()

# Make the spacing between the two axes a bit smaller
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.15)

# This looks pretty good, and was fairly painless, but you can get that
# cut-out diagonal lines look with just a bit more work. The important
# thing to know here is that in axes coordinates, which are always
# between 0-1, spine endpoints are at these locations (0,0), (0,1),
# (1,0), and (1,1). Thus, we just need to put the diagonals in the
# appropriate corners of each of our axes, and so long as we use the
# right transform and disable clipping.

d = .015 # how big to make the diagonal lines in axes coordinates
# arguments to pass plot, just so we don't keep repeating them
kwargs = dict(transform=ax.transAxes, color='k', clip_on=False)
ax.plot((1-d,1+d),(-d,+d), **kwargs) # top-left diagonal
ax.plot((1-d,1+d),(1-d,1+d), **kwargs) # bottom-left diagonal

kwargs.update(transform=ax2.transAxes) # switch to the bottom axes
ax2.plot((-d,d),(-d,+d), **kwargs) # top-right diagonal
ax2.plot((-d,d),(1-d,1+d), **kwargs) # bottom-right diagonal

# What's cool about this is that now if we vary the distance between
# ax and ax2 via f.subplots_adjust(hspace=...) or plt.subplot_tool(),
# the diagonal lines will move accordingly, and stay right at the tips
# of the spines they are 'breaking'

plt.show()
```