# Matplotlib how to collapse time gaps in datetime axis without changing axis from datetime to string?

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, twinx

I'm writing a stock trading application, and I want to show a chart with price data and multiple technical indicators plotted on the same graph.

I'm using the twinx() function for plotting multiple indicators along with price.

I don't know how to handle the time-gap on the chart when trading is closed. I have read several answers on SO and other places and they all say to convert datetime to string on the axis where I want to close the gap.

But this is not an option for me because for the multiple indicators I'm calculating on the spur of the moment and they have a shorter date-time range than the price data. It is convenient to just pass the datetime values and have the indicators plotted starting from the far right of the chart.

Is there a way to accomplish this? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You’re going to want to look at [broken axis plots](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/broken_axis.html)

Comment: @WilliamMiller Thanks v.much. I will check it out.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5656798/10659910) might be useful as well

Comment: @WilliamMiller Thanks v.much again. I will check that out too.

Comment: @WilliamMiller I checked out broken axis plots and found [this package](https://github.com/bendichter/brokenaxes) which might be an easy way to do what I want. If it works, I will post it as an answer. Thanks v.much again for the pointer.

Comment: No problem, I’m glad I pointed you in the right direction