# Discontinuous axis in Matplotlib with categorical variable on axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot of values w/ errorbars with a categorical variable on the X-axis, made using the `errorbar` method. I have followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656798/python-matplotlib-is-there-a-way-to-make-a-discontinuous-axis) to create a discontinuity in the X-axis (I'm only showing points with values > or < some absolute threshold).

[image]

So far so good, with one slight issue - the axis break ends up being exactly on a data point on each side, which makes it harder to read on the axis, and also, the datapoints themselves end up split in two, which is kind of awkward.

I would like the axis break to instead be *between* datapoints, something like:

`----(last value before break)--/ /--(first value after break)----`

Is there a way to do this?

The breakpoints are determined with `set_xlim`, and I'm not sure if there's a way to do move them off the datapoints with a categorical x-axis...

```
sort_res_h = sort_res_a[sort_res_a > threshold]
sort_res_l = sort_res_a[sort_res_a < -threshold]

ax0.errorbar(sort_res_a.index, sort_res_a, yerr=chg_dpm_err, fmt='o')
ax1.errorbar(sort_res_a.index, sort_res_a, yerr=chg_dpm_err, fmt='o')

ax0.set_xlim(xmax=sort_res_h.index[-1])
ax1.set_xlim(xmin=sort_res_l.index[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to share what I have been able to complete so far, although it is not a flawless solution. But maybe this will help you in any case. I would propose that you set your `xaxis` limits using the `ticks` positions, instead of the data. The problem is that if you take ticks as provided by default by `matplotlib`, sometimes there are more ticks than those that you see (for example there could be ticks before the minimum value in the xaxis or after the maximum). As in your case you seem to be setting the ticks, I think this should work (Replace the way you set your axes limits by this. I only provide the code for the `ax0`):

```py
# First we get current ticks positions
ax0_xticks_positions = ax0.get_xticks()
# then we get the distance between two ticks
ax0_ticks_distance = ax0_xticks_positions[1] - ax0_xticks_positions[0]

# percentage of tick separation that we want the axis to extend beyond/before the last/first tick
percentage_add = 0.5

# set the xlim to the last tick position plus a percentage of tick distance
ax0.set_xlim(xmax = ax0_xticks_positions[-1] + percentage_add*ax0_ticks_distance)
```

You can play around with `percentage_add` until you find a value that suits you. For `ax1` you would have to use the first tick:
`ax1.set_xlim(xmin = ax1_xticks_positions[0] - percentage_add*ax0_ticks_distance)`

The problem of this solution, is if the tick you use to fix the limit is outside the current axis limits. That would make the breakpoint go further than you would expect. To solve that, you can compare the tick position (for example `ax0_xticks_positions[-1]`) to the applicable axis limit (following the example `ax0.get_xlim()[-1]`). If the tick position is larger than the limit, you would have to use the second to last tick `ax0_xticks_positions[-2]`