# Matplotlib xticks ranges & labels issue

Tags: python, matplotlib, xticks

Could you please advise on how to solve next Matplotlib xticks ranges & labels issue I am facing with a couple of Python cases? I am trying to plot a couple of double charts (1 X 2) however, xticks ranges and labels showed are not in the way needed:

CASE 1) Starting point are 4 short dataframes as follow, after import libraries:

```
ye_mo_sales_Trial:
  YearMo TotSales
0 201807 296.8
1 201808 255.5
2 201809 225.2
3 201810 204.5
4 201811 245.3
5 201812 267.3

ye_mo_sales_Trial.dtypes
YearMo int64
TotSales float64
dtype: object


ye_mo_sales_Control:
  YearMo TotSales
0 201807 290.7
1 201808 285.9
2 201809 228.6
3 201810 185.7
4 201811 211.6
5 201812 279.8
6 201901 177.5

ye_mo_sales_Control.dtypes
YearMo int64
TotSales float64
dtype: object


ye_mo_cust_Trial:
  YearMo TotCust
0 201807 55
1 201808 48
2 201809 44
3 201810 38
4 201811 44
5 201812 49
6 201901 39

ye_mo_cust_Trial.dtypes
YearMo int64
TotCust int64
dtype: object


ye_mo_cust_Control:
  YearMo TotCust
0 201807 54
1 201808 50
2 201809 45
3 201810 36
4 201811 41
5 201812 50
6 201901 35

ye_mo_cust_Control.dtypes
YearMo int64
TotCust int64
dtype: object
```

Code to plot 1x2 charts is as follow:

```
Trial = 77
Control = 233
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 6))
labelTrial=("Trial Store: "+str(Trial))
labelControl=("Control Store: "+str(Control))
ax[0].plot(ye_mo_sales_Trial["YearMo"], ye_mo_sales_Trial["TotSales"], color = "b", label=labelTrial)
ax[0].plot(ye_mo_sales_Control["YearMo"], ye_mo_sales_Control["TotSales"], color = "g", label=label Control)
ax[1].plot(ye_mo_cust_Trial["YearMo"], ye_mo_cust_Trial["TotCust"], color = "b", label=labelTrial)
ax[1].plot(ye_mo_cust_Control["YearMo"], ye_mo_cust_Control["TotCust"], color = "g", label=labelControl)
ax[0].set_xlabel("Year-Month")
ax[0].set_ylabel("Total Sales")
ax[0].set_title("Trends based on Total Sales")
ax[0].legend()
ax[1].set_xlabel("Year-Month")
ax[1].set_ylabel("Total Customers")
ax[1].set_title("Trends based on Total Customers")
ax[1].legend()
plt.show()
```

and the output is:
[1x2 charts plot CASE 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeskH.png)
At the x axis, I am trying to show a range of 7 points: 201807, 201808, 201809, 201810, 201811, 201812 and 201901…how to fix my Python code to produce such output?

CASE 2) Similar to CASE 1, CASE 2 uses 4 shorter dataframes as follow:

```
ye_mo_sales_Trial2:
  YearMo TotSales
0 201902 235.0
1 201903 278.5
2 201904 263.5

ye_mo_sales_Trial2.dtypes
YearMo int64
TotSales float64
dtype: object


ye_mo_sales_Control2:
  YearMo TotSales
0 201902 244.0
1 201903 199.1
2 201904 158.6

ye_mo_sales_Control2.dtypes
YearMo int64
TotSales float64
dtype: object


ye_mo_cust_Trial2:
  YearMo TotCust
0 201902 45
1 201903 55
2 201904 48

ye_mo_cust_Trial2.dtypes
YearMo int64
TotCust int64
dtype: object


ye_mo_cust_Control2:
  YearMo TotCust
0 201902 47
1 201903 41
2 201904 33

ye_mo_cust_Control2.dtypes
YearMo int64
TotCust int64
dtype: object
```

Plotting Python Code for 1x2 charts is:

```
Trial = 77
Control = 233
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 6))
labelTrial=("Trial Store: "+str(Trial))
labelControl=("Control Store: "+str(Control))
ax1.plot(ye_mo_sales_Trial2["YearMo"], ye_mo_sales_Trial2["TotSales"], color = "b", label=labelTrial)
ax1.plot(ye_mo_sales_Control2["YearMo"], ye_mo_sales_Control2["TotSales"], color = "g", label=labelControl)
ax2.plot(ye_mo_cust_Trial2["YearMo"], ye_mo_cust_Trial2["TotCust"], color = "b", label=labelTrial)
ax2.plot(ye_mo_cust_Control2["YearMo"], ye_mo_cust_Control2["TotCust"], color = "g", label=labelControl)
ax1.set_xlabel("Year-Month")
ax1.set_ylabel("Total Sales")
ax1.set_title("Trends based on Total Sales")
ax1.legend()
ax2.set_xlabel("Year-Month")
ax2.set_ylabel("Total Customers")
ax2.set_title("Trends based on Total Customers")
ax2.legend()
plt.show()
```

And output is:
[1x2 charts plot CASE 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4wNy.png)

At the x axis, I am trying to show a range of 3 points: 201902, 201903 and 201904… how to fix my Python code to produce such output?

Thank you in advance for support given.

Comment: ...Is there a reason those images are upside down?

Answer (score 0):

The `xlim()` feature from the `matplotlib` library allows you to explicitly define your limits for the x-axis. See the documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html).

For **CASE 2**, try adding:

```
plt.xlim(201902, 201904)
```

Similarly for **CASE 1**, we can do the same thing. However, since it appears that dates are being used as `int` values, you will get values in the range that don't correspond to an actual year/month (e.g. 201813, 201814, etc.). So, you can try re-formatting the data to date/month values or you could try making a break in the x-axis of the graph to solely display the year/month values. At minimum, try adding the following line of code in before `plt.show()`:

```
plt.xlim(201807, 201901)
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656798/python-matplotlib-is-there-a-way-to-make-a-discontinuous-axis) that may help you with adding a break in the x-axis for **CASE 1**. Also, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608788/changing-the-tick-frequency-on-x-or-y-axis-in-matplotlib) as an alternative solution where you would explicitly assign the `xticks`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you paulitician27 unfortunately your recommendation for CASE 2 didn't work.

For CASE 2 I added the code line you recommended without successs. My new code incluiding your recommendation for your revision is as follow:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 6))
labelTrial=("Trial Store: "+str(Trial))
labelControl=("Control Store: "+str(Control))
ax1.plot(ye_mo_sales_Trial2["YearMo"], ye_mo_sales_Trial2["TotSales"], color = "b", label=labelTrial)
ax1.plot(ye_mo_sales_Control2["YearMo"], ye_mo_sales_Control2["TotSales"], color = "g", label=labelControl)
ax2.plot(ye_mo_cust_Trial2["YearMo"], ye_mo_cust_Trial2["TotCust"], color = "b", label=labelTrial)
ax2.plot(ye_mo_cust_Control2["YearMo"], ye_mo_cust_Control2["TotCust"], color = "g", label=labelControl)
ax1.set_xlabel("Year-Month")
ax1.set_ylabel("Total Sales")
ax1.set_title("Trends based on Total Sales")
ax1.legend()
ax2.set_xlabel("Year-Month")
ax2.set_ylabel("Total Customers")
ax2.set_title("Trends based on Total Customers")
ax2.legend()
plt.xlim(201902, 201904)
plt.show()
```

For CASE 2 it produced same 1X2 chats I did before include your line code:

[CASE 2 1X2 Charts with new line code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYmih.png)

Any other suggestion you may have for CASE 2?

Answer (score 0):

For CASE 2, I changed data type of the 4 dataframes in column YearMo from int64 to datetime64, so they look as:

```
YearMo datetime64[ns]
TotSales float64
dtype: object
```

I also changed Python code to plot the 1x2 charts as follow:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 6))
labelTrial=("Trial Store: "+str(Trial))
labelControl=("Control Store: "+str(Control))
ax[0].plot(ye_mo_sales_Trial2["YearMo"], ye_mo_sales_Trial2["TotSales"], color = "b", label=labelTrial)
ax[0].plot(ye_mo_sales_Control2["YearMo"], ye_mo_sales_Control2["TotSales"], color = "g", label=labelControl)
ax[1].plot(ye_mo_cust_Trial2["YearMo"], ye_mo_cust_Trial2["TotCust"], color = "b", label=labelTrial)
ax[1].plot(ye_mo_cust_Control2["YearMo"], ye_mo_cust_Control2["TotCust"], color = "g", label=labelControl)
ax[0].set_xlabel("Year-Month")
ax[0].set_ylabel("Total Sales")
ax[0].set_title("Trends based on Total Sales")
ax[0].legend()
ax[1].set_xlabel("Year-Month")
ax[1].set_ylabel("Total Customers")
ax[1].set_title("Trends based on Total Customers")
ax[1].legend()
plt.show()
```

I was expecting produce same acceptable result as I reached with CASE 1, however, xaxis shows more than 3 points range and overlapping:

[1x2 Charts CASE 2 changed dtype & Coding similar to CASE 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YXnz.png)

At the x axis, I am trying to show a range of 3 points: 2019-02, 2019-03 and 2019-04… how to fix my Python code to produce such output?

Thank you in advance for support given.