# Hide part of the axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'd like to use matplotlib to plot some points (x-y coordinates). There are pretty big x axis gaps between the points, so I'd like convert the x axis to a not "true to scale" format afterwards. Ideally, I'd just mask fragments of the x axis (it won't need labels).

Is there a way to easily do this without having to scale the points themselves?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python/Matplotlib - Is there a way to make a discontinuous axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656798/python-matplotlib-is-there-a-way-to-make-a-discontinuous-axis)