# Draw matplotlib broken axis on left side only

Tags: python, matplotlib

Matplotlib's [broken axis example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/broken_axis.html?highlight=broken%20axis) has a break on the left and the right side of the frame and is placed exactly in the middle of the y-axis.

[image]

1. How can I create an unbroken line on the right border and a broken axis on the left border?
2. Is there a keyword argument to manually adjust the horizontal whitespace in the broken axis?
3. Is it possible to decide where on the y-axis the break will be placed? For example, at 80% from the top border, or 20% from the top border?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The structure of the interrupted axis is created by deleting the top and bottom edges of the two graphs, so I have never seen a graph with only one side. The location of the interruption can be adjusted by the ratio of the height of the graphs.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656798/python-matplotlib-is-there-a-way-to-make-a-discontinuous-axis) is an example where the right axis is deleted and only the left one is used.

Comment: I think I can do it by installing [brokenaxes](https://github.com/bendichter/brokenaxes) library.

Comment: IIUC, the answer you link to doesn't exactly solve my issue. It breaks the x-axis instead of the y-axis, but it does that on the top and bottom line of the border/frame. In this case, I am looking for a way that it breaks only the top frame or the bottom frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Not breaking the right axis** Since the way to break the axis is to make two sets of axes, the only way I can think of the do this is to draw a line going from the top right corner of the lower axis to the bottom right corner of the upper axis. This can be done using [`transforms`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html) to get the relevant corners of the two axes in the axes coordinates of one of the axes

```py
# Get the points from the lower-right corner of ax1 
# to the top-right corner of ax2 in the axes coordinates
# of ax1
low = (1, 0)
high = ax1.transAxes.inverted().transform(
    ax2.transAxes.transform((1, 1))
)
```

and then plotting them with `transform=ax1.transAxes`

```py
ax1.plot(
    *list(zip(low, high)), "-k", 
    transform=ax1.transAxes, clip_on=False,   
    lw=ax1.spines.right.get_linewidth(),
)
```

2 and 3. **Adjust the whitespace and position of the break** This can be achieved using any way of creating different axes in `matplotlib`, such as passing `gridspec_kw` to `plt.subplots` e.g.

```py
gridspec_kw = dict(height_ratios=(1, 4), hspace=0.30)
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True, gridspec_kw=gridspec_kw)
```

As the name suggest `height_ratios` defines the ratios of the heights of the axes. `hspace` sets the vertical space between the two sets of axes (if you want to break the x-axis instead you can use `wspace`)

Applying these changes to the example you link, and removing the diagonal lines on the right hand side by changing

```py
ax1.plot([0, 1], [0, 0], transform=ax1.transAxes, **kwargs)
ax2.plot([0, 1], [1, 1], transform=ax2.transAxes, **kwargs)
```

to

```py
ax1.plot(0, 0, transform=ax1.transAxes, **kwargs)
ax2.plot(0, 1, transform=ax2.transAxes, **kwargs)
```

you get the following plot
[image]

Comment: I tested your suggestions.
1. How did you arrive at the coordinates `(1,1)` and `(1,1.2)`? 
2. `ax2.plot(...` does indeed fill the gap between the two subplots but does not remove the diagonal lines.

Comment: Ah sorry you also need to remove the diagonal lines. I've edited answer to include the lines you need to change to remove those. The 1.2 means 20% higher than the height of the lower y-axis. I just chose this by eye. I'm sure the exact values could be found using transforms if they are needed.

Comment: Thanks very much! I'm accepting your answer. Also, can I please trouble you for how to get the exact values from transforms? Or if you could point to me the relevant docs. I don't really understand.

Comment: I was interested to check myself so I changed the first part to use the transforms (and linked the tutorial)

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the line using transforms (after setting `transform=None`). It should work because its providing coordinates to `ax2.plot` and I checked that the color of the line wasn't accidentally set to white or that linewidth isn't 0.

Comment: I tested it and it worked fine for me. I also tried changing the line to red so I could see it and it looked correct.