# Blocking a big number from appearing in PLOT Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

Here's my issue : i have a dataframe that reads from a csv like this

```
DAY;FILE_TYPE
20210101;csv
20210102;xml
20210102;xml
20210102;xml
20210103;doc
```

i want to plot the count of evry type of file except the 'doc' file ;here is my code that reads from the file calculates counts in a crosstab and creates the chart:

```
df=pd.read_csv(r"/applis/prisme/informatica/version/scripts/test2.csv",sep=';')
tab=pd.crosstab(df['DAY'],df['FILE_TYPE'])
tab=tab.drop(['doc'],errors='ignore',axis=1)
fig=plt.figure()
tab.plot(kind='bar',figsize=(16,15))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 2, 1))
```

and this is my chart i get

[image]

Now my issue is in the plot: supposingly that i sized the yticks at maximum '2' what i wanna do is when the bar exceed from that value , i want it to be blocked at that value and a label bar appears on it indicating it's real value like this.

[image]

PS: i'm using python 2.7 (bar_label doesn'work for me)

Comment: you can `clip` the data or use a [broken axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656798/python-matplotlib-is-there-a-way-to-make-a-discontinuous-axis), or simply set a limit on the y-axis span

Comment: i used np.clip(pd.crosstab(df['DAY'],df['FILE_TYPE']),0,2) , and it is working fine to block my bar , but i'm still missing the bar_label that appears when my value exceed from the max value('2')

Comment: There is no automagic method ;) You have to add labels manually (using a loop).