How to break multiple y axis in matplotlib subplots
I have two dataframes from which I want to create a figure with two plots. The first corresponds to the daily temperature and the average temperature for each month. The second subplot shows the width of the average home range of a group of individuals and the width of the home range of single individuals for each month.
The plot succeeds quite well (see figure 1), however I would like to break up the two y axys of the home range plot to show the seasonal variations of the individuals that move less (in the image shown here they are too squashed).

For this reason I would like to break the two y axys as in the second figure shown here.

Here is my code:
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(12, 10), sharex=False,
                              gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [1, 3]})

# Plot 1: Daily temperature with mean monthly temperatures
sns.lineplot(data=temperature_df, x='date', y='temperature', ax=ax1, label='Daily Temperature')

# Convert year-month to datetime for plotting mean monthly temperatures
temperature_mean_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(temperature_mean_df['year1'].astype(str) + '-' + temperature_mean_df['month1'].astype(str), format='%Y-%B')
temperature_mean_df['month2'] = temperature_mean_df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%B')


sns.lineplot(data=temperature_mean_df, x='date', y='temperature', ax=ax1, label='Mean Monthly Temperature', color='red', marker='o')
ax1.axhline(0, color='grey', linestyle='--')
ax1.set_title('Daily temperature 2019/2020')
ax1.set_xlabel('')
ax1.set_ylabel('Temperature (°C)')
ax1.set_ylim(-2, 17)  # Set the y-axis limits from -3 to +13
ax1.legend()

# Plot 2: Home range amplitude
sns.lineplot(data=home_range_df, x='month1', y='HUP', hue='Tag', ax=ax2, legend=True, palette=palette19)
# Create a secondary y-axis
ax2_right = ax2.twinx()
# Plot the mean home range amplitude with error bars on the secondary y-axis
ax2_right.errorbar(home_range_mean_df['month1'], home_range_mean_df['mean'], yerr=home_range_mean_df['sem'], fmt='o', color='gray', alpha=0.5, capsize=5)
# Plot the mean home range amplitude on the secondary y-axis
sns.barplot(data=home_range_mean_df, x='month1', y='mean', ax=ax2_right, alpha=0.5, color='blue')
ax2.set_title('')
ax2.set_xlabel('Date')
ax2.set_ylabel('Habitat Usage Potential m2 (Individuals)')
ax2_right.set_ylabel('Mean Habitat Usage Potential m2')

ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(MonthLocator())
# Set the date format on the x-axis for both plots
date_formatter = DateFormatter('%b%Y')
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_formatter)
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_formatter)
plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha='right')
plt.setp(ax2.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha='right')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

What should i change to break the y axys of the home range plot?

Did you consider using a log scale for the y-axis? That might be easier to interpret than a broken axis.

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/5656798/13636407 and bendichter/brokenaxes
